# Send file over serial port from Python

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to send a file (a .jpg image in this case) over a serial port.

Currently it works by calling an external script:

```
subprocess.Popen(['./sendFile.sh','myImage.jpg']).communicate()
```

where `sendFile.sh` is:

```
cp /home/pi/$1 /dev/ttyAMA0
```

This method works but is somehow unstable. Sometimes my Python program stops after the transferring the file.

I'm wondering if there's a way to do this in Python instead of calling a script for help? I searched about XMODEM, but it seems like both ends must have it installed. I'm sending the image to a GPRS chip, which doesn't allow me to modify any code on it. So installing something to the receiving end is impossible.

Comment: Have you tried opening the device special file (`/dev/ttyAMA0`) and writing to it?

Comment: I do have some initialization to set the port and baudrate and I can write string to it by `serial.write(someString)`. Presumably I can transfer files like this, but I wasn't able to find the syntax.

Comment: does `shutil.copyfileobj(open('/home/pi/myImage.jpg','rb'), serial_obj)` work in your case? (note: use `with`-statement and close the files in the real code).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import serial
s = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyAMA0")
s.write(open("target.txt","rb").read())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `os.open` to directly open a dev:

```
f = os.open('/dev/ttyAMA0', os.O_RDWR)
f.write(open("myImage.jpg").read))
f.close()
```